# Why I use setState in async funtion not update state (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

**Why my _image not update?**

I need **_image** properties update when user pick new image from gallery or camera, but when user pick new images I use setState for set new value to **_image** but it didn't work(didn't update UI).

Here my code I have problem:
Sorry I cant full source because editor of stackoverflow complain to many code.

Statefull Class:
enum ChooseMedia { camera, gallery }

```
  File _image;

  void getImage(ChooseMedia media) async {
    if (media == ChooseMedia.camera) {
      var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      var pathLocal = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      await image.copy('${pathLocal.path}/profileImage.jpg').then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _image = image;
        });
      });
    }
    if (ChooseMedia.gallery == media) {
      var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      var pathLocal = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

      await image.copy('${pathLocal.path}/profileImage.jpg').then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _image = image;
        });
      });
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return PopupMenuButton(
          elevation: 5,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
          onSelected: (ChooseMedia media) {
            getImage(media);
          },
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<ChooseMedia>>[
            const PopupMenuItem<ChooseMedia>(
              value: ChooseMedia.gallery,
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.picture_in_picture,
                ),
                title: Text('From galaxy'),
              ),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<ChooseMedia>(
              value: ChooseMedia.camera,
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.camera),
                title: Text('Take picture'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: _image == null
                      ? AssetImage('assets/images/profile.jpg')
                      : FileImage(_image))),
        );
  }
```

Comment: is your file getting copied to the location you have provided? what does console log say ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing 'await' and 'then'
Just do

```
var copiedImage = await image.copy('${pathLocal.path}/profileImage.jpg');
setState(() {
    _image = copiedImage;
});
```

Comment: I use like you save but it not work, it just work first times and second times pick image it not update:                                                                                                           `var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      var pathLocal = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

      var saveFile = await image.copy('${pathLocal.path}/profileImage.jpg');
      setState(() {
        image = saveFile;
      });`

Comment: That's because the image path is always the same

Do something like this

    var pathLocal = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    if (_image != null) {
      _image.deleteSync();
    }
    setState(() {
      _image = null;
    });

    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    var copiedImage = await image.copy('${pathLocal.path}/${DateTime.now()}.jpg');
    setState(() {
      _image = copiedImage;
    });